# Why I can't reset my CCParticleSystemQuad from the parent CCLayer?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I've added an additional CCLayer to my "GameScene" that becomes visible (`[self addChild:_congratsScreen]`) whenever my character collects a given amount of objects on the screen.

Within my GameScene.h I've declared my child layer (`CClayer *congratsScreen`) and I'm synthesizing it on my GameScene.m. I'm allocating the child CCLayer in the GameScene's `init` method so it is holding the reference to the child layer in this instance variable.

On my GameScene I have a few `CCParticleSystemQuad` instances, and it's super simple to invoke both `stopSystem` and `resetSystem` to replay my particles animation, but if I try to do the same thing on the `CCParticleSystemQuad` that was initialized on the child layer, the `resetSystem` doesn't work after I remove the child from my GameScene and add it back again. Does something happens with the CCLayer's components once it is removed from a parent layer's scene?

I don't have the code at the moment so I will try to write some pseudo-code to illustrate how it's being done:

How it is being initialized on ChildLayer.m:

```
_sparkling= [CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"sparkling.plist"];
```

Then, somewhere on GameScene.m I have:

```
- (void) showCongrats {
  //pathetic way to create a modal panel
  [self setTouchable = NO];

  [[[self _congratsLayer] _sparkling] resetSystem];
  [self addChild:_congratsLayer];
}
- (void) hideCongrats {
  //let them continue playing
  [self setTouchable = YES];

  [[[self _congratsLayer] _sparkling] stopSystem];
  [self removeChild:_congratsLayer];
}
```

So, it works on the first time I invoke `showCongrats`, the reference is good and I can manipulate the particles, but once I hide the layer, continue playing the game and show the congratulations panel again, it shows a frozen animation of the particles from the last invocation, the `resetSystem` no longer works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would add some breakpoints in the code and walk through it but if I had to guess I would say that when you are calling removeChild you are losing the data that you had in your init method and something funky is happening.